# How to fill in the gaps in a query of totals with zeroes?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table with data like this

```
picks
20  
20  
20  
18  
17  
12  
12  
9   
9
```

This is the table but I need to get result like this.

```
Picks  Count
20     3   
19     0
18     1
17     1
16     0

...up to

1      12
```

How can we write query to get zero totals for data which doesn't exist in the table?

Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to generate all the numbers and then outer join it to your table.

```
with nos as ( select level as pick_id
              from dual
              connect by level <= 20 )
select nos.pick_id
       , count(*)  
from nos
     left outer join picks
          on nos.pick_id = picks.id
group by nos.pick_id
order by nos.pick_id desc ;
```